# Making an inline HTML element "not taking up space" without any layout-changing side-effects

Tags: html, css, layout

I was trying to make an element not occupying any space but still visible. I don't want any possible layout-changing side-effects, which means the elements should look **exactly** the same after making it not taking up space.

Almost all methods provided by Google, or related answers in StackOverflow, use absolute positioning. The problem is setting `position: absolute` to an inline element actually *changes* its layout behavior.

Take this really simple layout for example:

[A simple paragraph layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSw0R.png)

My intention is to make the blue text `<span>` *not* occupying space. I set it to `position: absolute`:

[After absolute positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfBEf.png)

We can see from the image that the second line of the `<span>` doesn't position from the start of the line anymore. It's lined up to the start position of the first line, which I assume, was to make sure the whole `<span>` remains a rectangular shape. But no matter what, the layout was modified after absolute positioning.

Some suggest wrapping a relative layout container around the `<span>`, but that won't work - as long as *one* absolute container is showing up, the layout breaks.

---

By the way, my intention on this was to emphasize a few words in a paragraph by inverting their `color` and `background-color`, and I had to make two perfect overlapping copies and style them separately in order to do so. I can't directly style one `<span>` because the background of multiple lines of text always overlap on the previous lines, cutting off the descenders of those letters when `line-height` is small, but that's another problem.

Comment: I'm really unclear on why this span should take up "no space". If you want to style the span, (for a highlight) then just use a span and style that.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks. The problem description was updated.